# How can i calculate the arithmetic mean in my code sample?

Tags: java, math

I write a code sample about calculate the aritmetic mean,i did lots of thing but some parts are missing/incorrect.

This is my code sample :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int thelargest;
    int thesmallest;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the list of number : ");
    String input2 = input.nextLine();

    String[] numbers = input2.split("\\s+");

    int[] result = new int[numbers.length];
    for (j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        result[j] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]);

    }

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("");
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("The Largest Number :  "
            + findTheLargestNumber(result));
    System.out.println("The Smallest Number :  "
            + findTheSmallestNumber(result));
    thelargest = findTheLargestNumber(result);
    thesmallest = findTheSmallestNumber(result);
    float arithmeticMean = (float) (result[i + j])// result.length;
            System.out.println("The Arithmetic Mean : " + arithmeticMean);
```

/*There is a mistake and  I tried to solve it but I didn't find any way to solve it.I want my programme to sum the results(numbers) and divide into number of result.(For example :10+20+30=60 and the aritmetic mean is 60/3=20.)Lastly,I think the mistake is about (float)(result[i+j]).

*/

```
}

public static int findTheSmallestNumber(int[] series) {
    int thesmallest = series[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < series.length; i++) {
        if (series[i] < thesmallest) {

            thesmallest = series[i];
        }
    }
    return thesmallest;
}

public static int findTheLargestNumber(int[] series) {
    int thelargest = series[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < series.length; i++) {
        if (series[i] > thelargest) {

            thelargest = series[i];
        }
    }
    return thelargest;
}
```

}

Thanks for everbody which gonna help to me .

Comment: `result[i + j]` this should throw an *ArrayIndexOutOfBounds* exception.

Comment: `result[i + j]` returns the element at the `i+j`-th position: (a) there might no item at this position and you will get an exception (b) even if there were an element at that position, there is no reason that it would be equal to the mean. You need to loop over the items and calculate the mean manually.

Comment: @assylias but I want to calculate the mean automaticly with my programme .How can i change that ?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Ok,but what am I gonna do to solve the problem  ?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static float getAirthmeticMean(int[] result){
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
       sum+=result[i]);
   }
   return (float)sum/result.length;
}
```

Comment: thank you @NoobUnChained but I want to ask one last question.Where should I write this in my code sample ?

Comment: Write that method inside the class like `findTheLargestNumber()` etc and call it passing the `result` array!!!

Comment: @NoobUnChained I can't do that can you show on a code sample ?

Comment: `System.out.println("The Arithmetic Mean : " + getAirthmeticMean(result));`

Comment: ok i did it but now the eclipse warns me about two errors about "i"?

 for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
       sum+=result[i]);(All of the "i" are shown like an error.)

Comment: @NoobUnChained are you there ?

Comment: Declare `int i` => `(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)`

Comment: but the same thing ?@NoobUnChained

Comment: @NoobUnChained I don't understand about your comment what to do ?Can you explain it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct is correct. The `result[i+j]` line doesn't make sense.  How about another function?

```
public static float calculateMean(int[] series) {
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + series[i];
  }
  return ((float)sum) / series.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add all the numbers in the array together in a for loop, and then divide by the length of the array.